# Count from mult tables with different pointers in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have this tables:

---

**Table 1 (a)** [ index | name ]

**Table 2 (b)** [ fk_index | code ] fk_index is pointing to a.index

**Table 3 (c)** [ c_index | fk_code ] fk_code is pointing to b.code

**Table 4 (d)** [ d_index | fk_code ] fk_code is pointing to c.fk_code

---

i want to show in a table like: | a.name | count( d.fk_code ) |

my attemp was:

```
 "SELECT a.name (SELECT COUNT(fk_code )
                      FROM d) quantity
          FROM a , d GROUP BY b.fk_index , b.code "
```

but is only showing 1 name with the count of all

Comment: Start with searching keyword like "MySQL COUNT" and "MySQL JOIN"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT a.`name`, count(d.`fk_code`) AS d_fk_code_count
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.`fk_index` = a.`index`
LEFT JOIN c ON c.`fk_code` = b.`code`
LEFT JOIN d ON d.`fk_code` = c.`fk_code`
GROUP BY a.`name`
```

Comment: i have only 2 names on table a, the 2 names are showing but the "d_fk_code_count" is showing 0 for both, and in my database have 7 enters for name1 and 1 enter for name2 =/

Comment: i really can use this "b.code = a.name" ? Sorry, i'm new in mysql

Comment: @GiuseppePiovesanSavastano I think i misunderstand your fields, I have updated.

Comment: oh, now works, thank you so much!!! And sorry, i didn't expressed myself correctly